# arp can't resolve another Windows 10

Tags: networking, arp

I have more than 10 devices on the same subnet.

On a Windows 10 Pro, arp can resolve every device's MAC except another Windows 10 Pro.

On the other Windows 10 Pro, it is the same, ie its arp can resolve every device's MAC except this Windows 10 pro.

I didn't go through the full permutations, but other devices on the network I tested have no trouble resolving these two Windows PC's MACs.

What could be happening?

Comment: How are the devices connected?

Comment: Wifi to the same AP.

Comment: How are other devices connected? Also Wi-Fi? Same AP? Is AP isolation perhaps enabled on the Wi-Fi access point?

Comment: YES! It so happened that during the investigation only these two happened to be on the same AP.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You indicate that the two PCs in question are connected to the network via the same Wi-Fi access point. It could be that “AP Isolation” is enabled on this access point, preventing any direct communication between the two PCs, which of course also includes ARP.

Other devices not connected via Wi-Fi to the same access point would not be affected by this setting.

If you turn off AP Isolation, everything should work as expected.

Comment: Yes, I plugged my PC to a wire port and things worked smoothly. I am curious how ARP works in this situation. If arp requests travel from the AP "upstream" to be broadcast to other physical segments of this same subnet, wouldn't the other PC on the same AP also receive my arp request like it receives from other wired devices?

Comment: No. That’s the point of AP Isolation. It’s basically like telling a switch not to forward traffic from one specific port to another specific port. Thankfully, we have fully switched networks these days, so packages won’t come back either.